# "message": "Aggregation stage not supported: '$lookup on multiple join conditions and uncorrelated subquery'"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, aws-documentdb, atlas

I have migrated Atlas Mongo DB 4.4.2 to AWS Document DB, Migration was Successfully done, While running the application I am getting below error.

**"message": "Aggregation stage not supported: '$lookup on multiple join conditions and uncorrelated subquery'"**

How can i solve this issue? Is there any alternate way to fix this issue?

Comment: Uncorrelated subquery for $lookup is not currently supported with Amazon DocumentDB. You'll have to do most of the work on the client side, run multiple joins and aggregate/apply conditions in the application.